# DAX average including zeroes

Tags: excel, powerpivot, calculated-columns, dax

My question is that I'd like to calculate a daily average taking into account days with zeroes.

Let me clarify it:

I'd like to calculate the average daily value of units for each category, with the following table:

[image: Data table]

When I sum up the values for each day and category, I get:

[image]

I'd like to include in the average calculation the zeroes.

I use the following code:

```
SUMMARIZE(
    Data,
    Data[Category],
    "Average",
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            Data,
            Data[Date],
            "Sum of Units",
            SUM(Data[Units])
        ),
        [Sum of Units]
    )
)
```

But the problem is that for category B it doesn't take into account those days with 0s.

Could you please guide me how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to add the missing zeroes, using UNION function:

```
SUMMARIZE(
    Data,
    Data[Category],
    "Average",
    AVERAGEX(
        UNION(
            SUMMARIZE(
                Data,
                Data[Date],
                "Sum of Units",
                SUM(Data[Units])
            ),
            ADDCOLUMNS(
                EXCEPT(
                    ALL(Data[Date]),
                    VALUES(Data[Date])
                ),
                "Sum of Units",
                0
            )
        ),
        [Sum of Units]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it would be to create a calendar table, which can then be used to count the number of days in any of your grouping periods.  This also means you can use non standard calendars, for example something like a 4-4-5

With a calendar table created you can leverage the `FIRSTDATE` and `LASTDATE` functions in DAX.

I recommend adding a past dates column to the calendar table, which can be created using DAX with the following formula.  The today function in DAX when used in a calculated column will only evaluate when the model is updated.

In my example I created a calculated column in the date table called Past_Dates

Past_dates   =IF( TODAY() > [Date], TRUE(), BLANK())

So for example if I create the following measures, the Today one just being used for illustration.

```
Start_date:=FIRSTDATE( Dates[Date] )

End_Date:=LASTDATE( Dates[Date])

Today:=TODAY()

EndPhased:=CALCULATE( LASTDATE( Dates[Date] ), Dates[Past_dates] = TRUE())
```

Which when added to an empty pivot table evaluate to the following.
Note that you would want to have year somewhere in the pivot if you have multiple years of data.

[image]

The idea of having the Past flag is to keep from counting days where they would not be any data due to being in the future.  So for example in September it would only use 11 days of sales and not the full 30.

As the below example shows, the finding of the start and end date even work on a Quarter basis.

[image]

So now that we have a way to get the Start and End date of a period, the next step is adding it into our Calculated measure.

In the below example, we are iterating though every unique Category name.  Within the category, we are summing the units sold, and then dividing by the number of days between EndPhased and Start_Date + 1.  Then averaging the results by the number of categories that have data in that period.

```
Average:=AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Data[Category] ),
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( SUM ( Data[Units] ), [EndPhased] - [Start_date] + 1 ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to have an underlying row with the zero value in it (in your initial Data table). Right now, you don't actually have a zero value for B on 02/01/2017. If you add a row with the values | 02/01/2017 | B | 0 | I believe you will see that the average accounts for it. As things stand for you right now, I believe the pivot table actually reflects no value (blank) rather than zero value, so the zero isn't currently counted for the average.